# Outlook FreeBusy method with OlBusyStatus returns value 5 when status is olWorkingElsewhere

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I made a script to evaluate the calendar status of several people and I'm using the FreeBusy method from Outlook.
It is working fine and returns the Free/Busy status. If I use the OIBusyStatus option it works fine too but when the appointment from the calendar is set as "Working Elsewhere", apparently it is returning the value "5".
Checking the documentation from Microsoft [FreeBusy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.freebusy), [OIBusyStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olbusystatus) , it should return "4" for that status.
Then, I'm not sure if the documentation is wrong or the value "5" means other thing, but I cannot find any documentation that explains that value.

This is because I'm looking for a method to determine if a calendar has a conflict between 2 different appointments in the same time slot.

I use my own calendar to do some testing, concluding that all the status return the value from the Microsoft documentation but the "Working Elsewhere", which returns "5".

Here is an example of my application:

```
    startDate = #1/15/2024#
    ' Assign a new AppointmentItem object to the objMeeting variable
    Set objMeeting = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    ' Set the properties of the meeting
    With objMeeting
        ' Assign the subject of the meeting
        .Subject = "Test meeting"
        ' Assign the location of the meeting
        .Location = "Room 1"
        ' Assign the date and time of the start of the meeting
        .Start = #1/15/2024#
        ' Assign the date and time of the end of the meeting
'        .End = #1/25/2024#
        ' Assign the body of the meeting message
        .Body = "This is a test meeting created by a macro."
        ' Assign the status of the meeting as requested
        .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    End With
    
    ' Assign the Recipients object to the objRecipients variable
    Set objRecipients = objMeeting.Recipients
    
        objRecipients.Add (myemail)

    For Each objRecipient In objRecipients
       'Get the availability for each recipients
       myVal = objRecipient.FreeBusy(startDate, 30, True)
    Next
```

In variable "myVal" is where appears the value "5" when I have an appointment as "Working Elsewhere".

Comment: I cannot reproduce this - can you see the value of 5 in OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy)? Open the appointment, click Item button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, select BusyStatus property.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Consider adding a link to the documentation.

Comment: I tried to add a small part of the code so you can reproduce easily. Also added links to Microsoft documentation.

Comment: "Working Elsewhere" returns 5 for an entry on my calendar. Other recipients not tested.

Comment: Thanks! So if you reproduce the same problem means that the official documentation from Microsoft is wrong, and the value "5" is the expected value for "Working Elsewhere".

Comment: 1 no repro and 1 repro with limited testing. Code with caution.

Comment: If there is a time slot with 2 or more appointments, for example, a "working elsewhere" and a "busy" appointment, the FreeBusy method is returning one of them, in this case the "working elsewhere". If I set a meeting using the Scheduling Assistant from Outlook, I see the same time slot blocked by a "busy" appointment, which means that a "busy" appointment has more priority to be reported in Outlook Scheduling Assistant than in FreeBusy method. Is that correct? Is there another method more similar to Outlook Scheduling Assistant or is possible to change the periodization to report?